# Ktor Websocket chat server - ERROR: undefined DISCONNECTED

Tags: websocket, ktor

I'm following [this](https://ktor.io/docs/creating-web-socket-chat.html#understanding-the-project-configuration) tutorial to get started with the Ktor project.
After trying the echo server **ws://localhost:8080/chat** (tried 0.0.0.0 as well and different browsers) on https://www.websocket.org/echo.html, I always get an error:

```
ERROR: undefined

DISCONNECTED
```

Browser console shows only this:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/chat?encoding=text' failed: 
doConnect @ echo.js:136
```

Server is running (or should be):

```
2021-04-27 10:19:55.431 [main] INFO  Application - No ktor.deployment.watch patterns specified, automatic reload is not active
2021-04-27 10:19:55.624 [main] INFO  Application - Responding at http://0.0.0.0:8080
```

There is no special configuration, just the one from the tutorial.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it in Firefox and Chrome browsers under Linux. What web browser and OS do you use? Also, I suggest trying it in incognito mode.

Comment: macOS Big Sur, Chrome/Safari

Comment: Tried Firefox and error is the same

Comment: Are you able to connect to the echo server using a different WebSockets client, e.g browser extension?

Comment: I can connect to the echo server with this app https://websocket-client.com/ - basically, a desktop client. However, no idea, what's under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility might be your CORS settings. Allowing anyHost worked for me:

```
install(CORS) {
    allowMethod(...)
    allowHeader(...)
    ...
    anyHost() // DO NOT USE THIS IN PRODUCTION!
}
```

Surprisingly, using `hosts.add("localhost:8080")` did not work for me. I had to use `anyHost()` when running my frontend from localhost:8080.

Note that you should not use `anyHost()` in production code.